# What happened to Alucard after Castlevania: Symphony of the Night? (Possible Spoilers)

Tags: castlevania-series

At the end of SOTN, Alucard says he is going to

> hide himself from humanity forever.

But, he appears later on in the series. What happened during that time, if it is ever told?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a Japanese-only, internet radio drama titled [Akumajō Dracula X: Tsuioku no Yasōkyoku](http://castlevania.wikia.com/wiki/Castlevania:_Nocturne_of_Recollection) (悪魔城ドラキュラX：追憶の夜想曲) (Castlevania: Nocturne of Recollection), Alucard lived with Maria for a while. [The script](https://archiveofourown.org/works/8197535/chapters/18780116) appears to play up the dedicated girlfriend/wife angle. The drama ends with them as a happy couple, more or less. There is no further mention of Alucard's life until his appearance in Aria of Sorrow.